# How do I statically assert that a static_cast is noexcept?

Tags: c++, static-cast, static-assert, noexcept

I have a functor to perform static casts from any type to a specific type, defined in this way:

```
template <typename T_Out>
struct cast_to {
    template <typename T_In>
    T_Out operator()(T_In&& value) const noexcept {
        return static_cast<T_Out>(value);
    }
};
```

Now, I would like to restrict the use of the functor to those static casts expressions that are declared, implicitly or explicitly, as `noexcept`. The idea is to add some static assertion in the `operator()` function. So far, I've tried with two constexpr expressions:

```
std::is_nothrow_constructible<T_Out, decltype(value)>::value
```

and

```
noexcept(static_cast<T_Out>(value))
```

Both seems to work as I expect (actually, I've seen that the first check includes also the other, at least on GCC). Which approach should I prefer? Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how technically correct you want to go. As you have said, both options achieve the intended goal - prevent compilation. The difference is:

- std::is_nothrow_constructible test will always evaluate to either true or false, making your assertion pass or fail.
- noexcept test will either evaluate to true, to false, or will fail to compile inner static_cast check if you pass arguments that don't convert at all.

I would go with one of the following:

1. SFINAE check for std::is_nothrow_constructible
2. SFINAE check for std::is_constructible, static_assert for noexcept

Option 2 might have better diagnostics, but option 1 may be more technically correct. It's personal preferences.